# Does the collection of bounded continuous functions characterize probability law?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X,Y :(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}) \to \mathbb{R}$ be two r.v.'s defined on a probability space $\Omega$, and $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ the collection of all real bounded continuous function.  I'm wondering whether the following holds:
$$\mathbb{E}[ f(X) ] = \mathbb{E}[f(Y)] ,\enspace \forall f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})\implies \mathbb{P}_X = \mathbb{P}_Y .$$

In the above $\mathbb{P}_X\,(\mathbb{P}_Y)$ is defined as the law of $X\,(Y)$, i.e., $ \mathbb{P}_X(A) = \mathbb{P}(X\in A)$. My guess is that this is true.

My attempt: Actually, for any open set $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have the following: Define $g_n(x) = [ n\cdot d(x,G^c)] \wedge 1$, it's clear that $ 0\leq g_n \leq 1$ and $(g_n) \uparrow \mathbb{I}_B$(the indicator function of $B$). Since each $g_n \in C_b$,
$$
  \mathbb{E}[ f_n(X)] =  \mathbb{E}[f_n(Y)] \enspace \forall n\implies \mathbb{P}_X(G) =  \mathbb{P}_Y(G).
$$
In the last line I take the limit $n \to \infty$ and apply the dominated convergence theorem( notice that the sequence $g_n$ is uniformly bounded) to interchange the limit and the integral. This shows that at least the two probability measures agree on open sets.

The next step is to show that for any Borel subset $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, similar result holds as in the case of open sets. I try to show this by defining the collection $L = \{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}): \exists \{f_n\}_n \subseteq C_b, \, (f_n) \to \mathbb{I}_B \, (Lebesgue)a.e. , 0\leq |f_n| \leq C \text{ for some C>0}\}$, and my goal is to show that it's actually a d-system(or a $\lambda$-system), and along with the fact that the topology $\mathcal{T} \subseteq L$, it then follows from the $\pi$-$\lambda$- theorem that $L = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

However, I fail to show $L$ is indeed a d-system, so I'm doubting that this argument doesn't work. I hope that someone can provide a complete argument, or if the statement is false, providing a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed the case. Instead of the Dynkin class argument, you can conclude using that the open sets are generator of $ \mathcal B_ℝ$ closed under intersection, so $ℙ_X(G) = ℙ_Y(G)$ for all open sets $G$ implies $ℙ_X = ℙ_Y$ by the [uniqueness theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniqueness_of_Measures) for measures.

Comment: Thanks! I still have a question. It seems that the argument can be generalized to any Polish space, instead of just $\mathbb{R}$. Is this also true in this setting?

Comment: Yes - in fact this works in any metric space $(E,d)$ equipped with its Borel-σ-algebra, and instead of $C_b(ℝ)$ one can take even smaller classes, e.g. bounded Lipschitz continuous functions, and even compactly supported bounded Lipschitz continuous functions, if $E$ is locally compact. See Achim Klenke's *Probability Theory*, §13. In $(ℝ^d, \mathcal B_{ℝ^d})$, we can do much better, e.g. the class $ x ↦ e^{i\langle t,x\rangle}, t ∈ ℝ^d$ suffices (a restatement of the fact that the characteristic function determines a finite measure uniquely).

Answer (score 3):

I think you're overcomplicating things.  Simply take $L = \{ B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) : P_X(B) = P_Y(B)\}$.  Then it is quite simple to show that $L$ is a $\lambda$-system using only elementary properties of probability measures.  (Indeed, the definition of a $\lambda$-system was pretty much invented to make this example work.)  And your first step showed exactly that $\mathcal{T} \subset L$.

Generally, the way to think about using the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem is this.  You are trying to show that all sets in some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ have some property Z.   You show, using the definition of property Z, that the collection $\mathcal{L}$ of all sets with property Z is a $\lambda$-system.  That is, that the universe $\Omega$ has property Z, that property Z is preserved under taking countable disjoint unions, and so on.  Then you come up with a smaller collection of sets for which you are able to prove, by some direct argument, that property Z holds.  You verify that this smaller collection is a $\pi$-system (closed under intersections) and that it generates $\mathcal{B}$.  Then you invoke the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem and you are done.